# What are the benefits of the new teaming driver?

Tags: linux, bonding

When compiling a 3.3 kernel, I noticed that a new driver called teaming was added to the networking system. According to [the relevant commit](https://git.kernel.org/linus/3d249d4ca7d0ed6629a135ea1ea21c72286c0d80) teaming is a userspace-driven alternative to bonding.

Has anyone been testing this out? Is it faster or better than the old tried-and-true bonding driver? What would be the advantages of changing?

Comment: You might get better mileage by posting to unix.se. Interesting question though, +1.

Comment: now released in RHEL 7 and CentOS 7, any update about this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like the advantages of changing right now are "none at all" inasmuch as the project has only just been added to the kernel, has very little documentation, and is self-described as being "still in its dipers[sic] atm".

In the long run, a userspace networking bonding driver could have some of the same benefits that FUSE (the userspace filesystem interface) brings to the world of filesystems -- primarily that it's much easier to develop and experiment with different policies, protocol implementations, and so forth.  By simplifying the in-kernel code and pushing the complexity into userspace, you can also end up with a solution that is more robust in the event of failures and that allows for more agile responses to bugs and feature requests and so forth.

[This presentation](http://www.pirko.cz/teamdev.pp.pdf) (warning:PDF) describes the motivation and goals of the project.  Primarily, they're looking to replace the legacy bonding code which is bloated and complicated with something that is smaller, easier to maintain, and more performant.

Comment: This makes sense when you realize that there are currently [seven](https://linuxcluster.wordpress.com/2010/01/08/linux-bonding-modes/) different bonding modes in the kernel driver. It's clear there is no real agreement on what "bonding" is, or what it's good for, or how precisely to get the desired benefits.